# Python Selenium Click Div with white space at the end

Tags: python, selenium

I have the following div:

```
<div role="button" tabindex="0" aria-pressed="true" class="myclassnamepicker selected" aria-label="Stack Overflow " >
```

I'm trying click the div by using the following:

```
browser.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@class='myclassnamepicker'][contains(text(),'Stack Overflow')]").click()
```

It doesnt click the div and throws no error.

If i an the extra space at the end of the code like this:

```
browser.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@class='myclassnamepicker'][contains(text(),'Stack Overflow ')]").click()
```

I get:

```
no such element: Unable to locate element
```

I've tried the following:

```
  #browser.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@class='myclassnamepicker'][text='Stack Overflow')]").click()
  #browser.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@aria-label='Stack Overflow']/div[@class='myclassnamepicker' and text()='Stack Overflow']").click()
  #browser.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@class='myclassnamepicker'][normalize-space(text()) = 'Stack Overflow' ").click()
```

And all give an error:

```
no such element: Unable to locate element
```

Please help. Thanks.

##UPDATE

here's the real html

```
<div role="button" tabindex="0" aria-pressed="true" class="sportsbook-outcome-cell__body selected" aria-label="Stack Overflow " >
   <div class="sportsbook-outcome-body-wrapper">
      <div class="sportsbook-outcome-cell__label-line-container">        <span class="sportsbook-outcome-cell__label">Stack Overflow</span>    </div>
      <div class="sportsbook-outcome-cell__elements">
         <div class="sportsbook-outcome-cell__element"></div>
         <div class="sportsbook-outcome-cell__element"><span class="sportsbook-odds american default-color">-380</span></div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you share the URL?

Comment: its a private site. Is there any other information you need from me?

Comment: Post some more of the HTML code. You have given `div` tag HTML and using `span` in xpath.

Comment: @pmadhu updated the original post with the real HTML

Comment: Try this xpath once:  `//div[@class='sportsbook-outcome-cell__body selected']//spam[contains(text(),'Stack Overflow')]`

Comment: @pmadhu no good

Answer (score 0):

`"Stack Overflow "` is the value of `aria-label` attribute, not a text.

With full value including the white space use

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.myclassnamepicker[aria-label="Stack Overflow "]')
```

or for partial match without the whitespace you can use `^=` for start with

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.myclassnamepicker[aria-label^="Stack Overflow"]')
```

With `xpath` you need to include both the classes in `class=...`

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//span[@class="myclassnamepicker selected"][contains(@aria-label, "Stack Overflow")]')
```

or use `contains()` for one class

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//span[contains(@class, "myclassnamepicker")][contains(@aria-label, "Stack Overflow")]')
```

Comment: Thanks for trying but its still not clicking the element with the white space

Answer (score 0):

It's not actually a text so, `contains(text(), 'Stack Overflow')` will not work.

Instead use this **xpath** :

```
//div[contains(@aria-label,'Stack Overflow')]
```

use it like this :

```
browser.find_element_by_xpath("//div[contains(@aria-label,'Stack Overflow')]").click()
```

**Update 1 :**

There are basically `3-4 ways to click in Selenium`. I would use this `xpath :` `//span[text()='Stack Overflow']/ancestor::div[contains(@aria-label,'Stack Overflow')]` to illustrate the `.click()`

**Code trial 1 :**

```
time.sleep(5)
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[text()='Stack Overflow']/ancestor::div[contains(@aria-label,'Stack Overflow')]").click()
```

**Code trial 2 :**

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[text()='Stack Overflow']/ancestor::div[contains(@aria-label,'Stack Overflow')]"))).click()
```

**Code trial 3 :**

```
time.sleep(5)
button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[text()='Stack Overflow']/ancestor::div[contains(@aria-label,'Stack Overflow')]")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", button)
```

**Code trial 4 :**

```
time.sleep(5)
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(button).click().perform()
```

**Imports :**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
import time
```

Comment: Same issue, it clicks all elements except the ones that have the white space at the end

Comment: Can you share the page url if it's not private ?

Comment: sorry for the delay, its draftkings.com

Comment: @Youngbuck2 :  Updated above with 4 code trials, I hope it will help you past the issue.